# F12 console window JavaScript browser errors when browsing to a WIndows 2012 website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed an ASP .NET application with a JavaScript Google Map on the home page to a Windows 2012 website. Now when I browse to the application it comes up fine except the Google Map never loads. On the F12 Console windows debugger here are the errors I'm getting:

> SEC7120: Origin http://mymachinename not found in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
>
> SCRIPTING7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network error 0X80700013, Could not
>   complete operation due to error 80700013.
>
> getPreferences failed when constructing GPToolsService: undefined

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        var map;

        MoW.ready(function () {
            map = new MoW.Map({
                target: 'MoWmap'
            });
        });

        window.onload = function () {

            MoW.ready(function () {

                if (document.getElementById('<%= KMLOPString.ClientID %>').value !== "") {
                    var overlayPropertiesOP = {
                        "name": "Openations KML",
                        "url": document.getElementById('<%= KMLOPString.ClientID %>').value,
                        "type": MoW.protocols.KMLProtocol.TYPE.STRING,
                        "description": "Demonstrating KML overlay",
                        "mapTypeId": "google.map.mapTypeId.ROADMAP"
                    };

                    var newOverlayObjectOP = MoW.Factory.createKMLOverlay(overlayPropertiesOP);

                    map.addOverlay(newOverlayObjectOP, {
                        showAlert: true

                    });

       //             map.setBasemap(MoW.Basemap.ID.ROADMAP);
                }

                if (document.getElementById('<%= KMLESString.ClientID %>').value !== "") {
                    var overlayPropertiesES = {
                        "name": "Exercises KML",
                        "url": document.getElementById('<%= KMLESString.ClientID %>').value,
                        "type": MoW.protocols.KMLProtocol.TYPE.STRING,
                        "description": "Demonstrating KML overlay",
                        "mapTypeId": "google.map.mapTypeId.ROADMAP"
                    };

                    var newOverlayObjectES = MoW.Factory.createKMLOverlay(overlayPropertiesES);

                    map.addOverlay(newOverlayObjectES, {
                        showAlert: true

                    });
                }

         //       map.setBasemap(MoW.Basemap.ID.ROADMAP);

            });

        }


        function kmlBtnClick() {

            var overlayProperties = {
                "name": "Example KML Overlay",
                "url": document.getElementById('<%= KMLESString.ClientID %>').value,
                "type": MoW.protocols.KMLProtocol.TYPE.STRING,
                "description": "Demonstrating KML overlay"
            };

            var newOverlayObject = MoW.Factory.createKMLOverlay(overlayProperties);

            map.addOverlay(newOverlayObject, {
                showAlert: true
            });

            map.setBasemap(google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: could you please share the code you are using to load the google map? also, try to add the cors in web.config file by using this code: `<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>`

Comment: I just added it back to the main post.

Comment: Adding <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> does not change anything. I still get all of the same errors.

Comment: One thing that does work is if I publish it as a Web Application and using localhost works. It's just when it's published as a website to IIS is where it fails.

Comment: make sure you install this CORS module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module)